# How to get a variable from a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I have a class that creates a server with multithreading. With the help of multithreading, I can connect several users at the same time. In one stream, the `QByteArray Data` is written, but I need this variable in the lane or in the lane heder, so that I can output this line (i.e., `QByteArray Data`). How I can tranfer var `Data` in my main function or header main?

I want write `Data` in QLable or somthing...

main.c

```
#include "groundstation.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "server.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GroundStation w;

    Server wServer;
    wServer.StartServer();
    //qDebug() << ServerThread::getString();

//    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    //label->setText((QString));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer (parent)
{
}

void Server::StartServer(){

    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234)){
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }

}

void Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << "Connecting...";
    ServerThread *thread = new ServerThread(socketDescriptor, this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

sever.h

```
    #ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>
#include "serverthread.h"

class Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    void StartServer();

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);
};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

serverthread.cpp

```
    #include "serverthread.h"

ServerThread::ServerThread(int id, QObject *parent) :
    QThread (parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = id;
}

void ServerThread::run(){
    //thread starts here
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Starting thread";
    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor)){
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client connected";

    //make this thread a loop
    exec();
}

void ServerThread::readyRead(){
    Data = socket->readAll();

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

    socket->write(Data);
}

void ServerThread::disconnected(){
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";
    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

serverthread.h

```
#ifndef SERVERTHREAD_H
#define SERVERTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class ServerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QByteArray Data;

    explicit ServerThread(int id, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

public slots:

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;

};

#endif // SERVERTHREAD_H
```

Comment: "With the help of multithreading, I can connect several users at the same time" - Threads are *not at all* the only way to do that.

Comment: Can I get a variable `Data` from the thread I need? I do not know how to make another

Comment: All threads share the same address space (but have their own stack). So all threads can access all variables (except stack variables and thread local variables). But you need synchronization to avoid race conditions. Threads are deceptively *complicated* and *difficult* to get right. Be careful.

Comment: Since you are using Qt, normally you'd have `ServerThread` emit a signal with `Data` as its parameter. Then whichever class is interested in that data would connect a slot to that signal. Qt handles passing signals between threads automatically.